# Left " and" inference rule G3cp

Tags: predicate-logic, proof-theory

If you are at the stage of $$((P\supset Q) \wedge (Q\supset \bot)) \Longrightarrow (P \supset \bot)$$

And then you apply an $L\wedge$ rule, 
Why do you get $$(P \supset Q),(Q\supset\bot)),P \Longrightarrow \bot$$

instead of  $$( P \supset Q), (Q \supset \bot) \Longrightarrow (P \supset Q)$$

Comment: You don't need to write $=>$; you can write $\Longrightarrow$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have to start (top-down) from :

> $(P⊃Q),(Q⊃⊥),P \Longrightarrow ⊥$

and then apply $R \supset$ to get :

> $(P⊃Q),(Q⊃⊥) \Longrightarrow (P \supset ⊥)$

followed by $L \land$ to get :

> > $((P⊃Q) \land(Q⊃⊥)) \Longrightarrow (P \supset ⊥)$.

The "final step" must be $R \supset$ again, to reach :

> $\Longrightarrow ((P⊃Q) \land(Q⊃⊥)) \supset (P \supset ⊥)$.

---

We have to note that we can "read" the *sequent calculus* as a formalization of the *derivability* relation.

If we replace $\Longrightarrow$ with the tunstile : $\vdash$, we get :

> $(P⊃Q),(Q⊃⊥),P \vdash ⊥$

which represent a quite trivial derivation :

1) $P⊃Q$ --- assumption

2) $Q⊃⊥$ --- assumption

3) $P$ --- assumption

> 4) $⊥$ --- by *modus ponens* twice.

Applying the *Deduction Theorem* twice, we get :

5) $(P⊃Q) \supset ((Q⊃⊥) \supset (P⊃⊥))$

which, by [Exportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_%28logic%29), is equivalent to :

6) $((P⊃Q) \land (Q⊃⊥)) \supset (P⊃⊥))$.

Thus, we have derived :

> $\vdash ((P⊃Q) \land (Q⊃⊥)) \supset (P⊃⊥))$.

Comment: The question starts from where you have done right implication rule.    But what is the point of applying the left and rule if you get the same?  How do you do latex in comments?

Comment: actually I understand

Comment: @user204450 - it is not clear to me your comment ... reading bottom-up mu proof, you have to apply first $R \supset$ because the "main" conncetive is $\supset$. Then you can choose : first $L \land$ and then $R \supset$ or viceversa : the final result will not change.